# Some issue with the country, state and city dropdown in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

There are 3 tables one for country, 2nd one for state and the last one for city. In another table named address I have city_id only. What I need is when I add a new address I want the state dropdown to be dynamically populated when I select a country and same for city. As there is no relation between address table and country table. How can I link address to country and state. I wanna show them all in dropdowns. The problem is how do I use the country and state controller object in address controller.

Comment: For the best answers, post representative DDL and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the problem. This can be done by the following code.

`$countries=$this->Address->City->State->Country->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Country.id','Country.countryName')));
$states=$this->Address->City->State->find('list',array('fields'=>array('State.id','State.stateName')));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to set the relations between your models: Address BelongsTo City, City BelongsTo State, State BelongsTo Country. Then when you retrieve an address from the database, it will also automatically retrieve the state and the country, unless you specify otherwise.

Here is some info on model associations: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together (you didn't say what version of CakePHP you're using so I linked to the latest one).